# Creating a new Galaxy entirely, or just make minor Changes to an already existing one?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, galactic

I'm really struggling with making my world, so I thought I would make it broad.

Is it necessary to invent an entirely new galactic system for the sake of originality, or is it acceptable to write about an already existing galaxy, but make minor tweaks to it's color or shape as to not stealing the universe's idea?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding SE. We generally discourage broad questions as our forum is dedicated to speculation that helps refine detail rather than set scenes, if you will. That said, I suspect that your question is better re-worded as 'can I use someone else's story universe and tweak it to be original, or do I need to start from scratch?' If that's the case, this question could be seen as opinion based and the answer will rely on the degree of modification you intend to apply. A helpful maxim however; to steal from one source is plagiarism. To steal from many is research.

Comment: What do you mean by "already existing galaxy"?

Comment: If you're talking about using actual locations (e.g. the Andromeda galaxy) then go for it. The universe doesn't care.

Comment: @TimBII I meant the universe that we live in. There are many many multi-verses, but I was referring to the place that we live.

Comment: @JakobLovern Thanks, I just don't want to claim a part of the universe without it's permission.

Comment: Right. Well, first of all the existence of multiverses is not what I would call fact just yet; I think science has a ways to go before we can make that claim. :) Second, where possible I always recommend working in the universe and galaxy we currently have. In Sci Fi and fantasy, you already have enough of your world to explain inside your story; don't make it harder by changing your physics as well unless you have to. That of course, is just my opinion. :)

Comment: @TimBII I appreciate your opinion, but my story takes place in another galaxy, with aliens (according to human categorization).

Comment: Right. well then as Jakob says, feel free to take any galaxy you like. He's right; they don't care. Bioware for instance didn't have to pay a license fee for Mass Effect Andromeda, basing it in the Andromeda galaxy. Even Star Wars being in an unnamed galaxy far far away wasn't intended to avoid copyright in any manner, George Lucas just wanted the flexibility to name systems and locations at will without someone fact checking star configurations and complaining about continuity. (Seriously, he was just obfuscating the setting so that he could design his own tech trees.)

Comment: If you are concerned about real galaxy's inhabitants suing you, you can give your galaxy a fictitious name, and put a disclaimer: "This is a work of fiction. Any names or characters, businesses or places, events or incidents, are fictitious. Any resemblance to actual persons, living or dead, or actual events is purely coincidental."

Comment: @Alelxander. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Please explain why you would need a whole different galaxy, especially one with only minor changes, given that there are an estimated 100-400 billion stars in this one.

Comment: This is a very broad question, as written, but I think an important concept and entirely appropriate for this forum, as it gets at the heart of why we're all here! Since you say you're struggling at making a world, perhaps in stead of asking such a broad umbrella question, try to come up with two or three serious sticking points in your writing. What is it you're really having difficulty with? That might be a better strategy to approach with and will certainly get you better answers.

Comment: Why do you need details about the physical properties of a galaxy? What is its role in the world you're building?

Comment: `stealing the universe's idea` ... LMAO

Comment: @elemtilas I meant in my initial question, that the world itself was too broad, so maybe I could go for a more simple thing first, like where in the universe is my planet located? What is the solar system like? and stuff like that.

Comment: @HDE226868 The role is that the main opposition takes place inside of this new galaxy, I imagine Guardians of the Galaxy when coming up with space related stuff, like the Celestial head called "Know-where"

Answer (score 1):

When you talk about a galaxy, do you talk about the political/social setting or the shape of the spiral arms? Copying the shape of the spiral arms is no problem at all.

When you talk about acceptable, what is the context? Things that might be entirely OK when you play a pen-and-paper roleplaying game with a couple of friends would be unacceptable when you try to write and then publish a novel.

- Generally speaking, when you do not publish just about anything goes.
- Copying distinctive names is a bad idea. Copying general concepts is OK. You can probably have a distant galaxy where the emperor uses armored troops to fight a rebellion. Calling the deputy archvillain Darth is a bad idea. Calling him Darth Vader is a very bad idea.

Comment: The phisical/color scheme of the galaxy is what I was looking for, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

**It's completely acceptable!**

We regularly create...

- Fictional companies within existing Earth cities.
- Fictional cities within existing Earth countries.
- Fictional countries on Earth, which I propose exists.<sup>*citation needed*</sup>
- Fictional stars, planets, and locations within the Milky Way.

In fact, it's often much simpler to start with something that exists and modify it to meet your needs.  New authors are often caught up in the details, not yet having learned when focus is needed and when it's not.  Inventing an entire galaxy, for example, just to tell a story on one world (where all you may need is to define some constellations for that world), is a ton of work without value — unless you intend to write a slew of stories within that galaxy.

But even then, it's frequently better to invent it on the go.  Terry Pratchett's *Discworld* was invented that way — and sometimes he changed the rules.  The Discworld of his early stories is not in every detail the same as in his last.

So, modify away.  Build only as much as you need and move forward with your story.

*One last point.  While I wouldn't be at all surprised for an enterprising lawyer to step up and claim to represent the Universe's best interests.  I suspect you might not have deep enough pockets for one to be well enough motivated — and I'm fairly sure the Universe, itself, won't mind too much if you copy its structure for the sake of your story.  :-)*